# Cucumber can not find the input or select the dropdown box well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

As usual, I use the fire-path to locate the element of my web application.
However, my testing framework is cucumber+capybara. My web application is based on ruby on rails.
Capybara support some high level keyword to do web application testing like "click_on", "select", "fill_in" and so on.
The problems I met are:

- One drop-down box id is "product_id" and one value is "TEST"
  However, the code like 'select "TEST", :from => "product_id"' can not work.
  The step is passed, but the selection is not changed as expected.
  The html code is shown bellow:

```html
<div class="eso-greybox">
<div class="option">
<label>Product</label>
<select id="product_id" data-method="POST" data-remote="true" data-url="/automatic_test/qu_for_product" data-value="16" name="product[id]">
<option value="66">TEST</option>
<option value="55">test_data</option>
```

- one input id is "clone-input", I try to 'fill_in "clone-input", :with => "hello" but cucumber output one error like no filed 'clone-input' found.
  The html code is shown bellow:

```html
<input id="clone-input" placeholder="test "/>
```

some my cucumber & capabara & rails gem versions are:

```html
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-api-steps (0.13)
cucumber-core (1.5.0)
cucumber-rails (1.4.5)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
capybara (2.0.3)
jquery-rails (3.1.4)
pry-rails (0.3.4)
rails (3.2.22.2)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-observers (0.1.2)
rails_autolink (1.1.4)
```

How to fix the two issues?
the fire-path can get the xpath, but the cucumber can not find them? why?

Comment: Show the relevant parts of you html.  Also, how are you determining whether or not the select has changed?

Comment: have updated the question again and posted the html code. some veriftion are failed in the later steps and according to the output html for the failed page, I find the select had not been changed.

Comment: can you show your cucumber / capybara code? You might have to increase the wait time for capybara.

Comment: the steps are ' visit "/home"; select "TEST", :from => "product_id"'. I do not think it is the time problems. From the page.html, all elements are shown well. And even before I select the item, I make it "sleep 10s". The select will not be changed, either.